# How to write a mysql stored procs using if else statement?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I'm having a problem with my stored procs. So basically I have to call this stored procs when it meets with the condition but when I call it, it does not show the row selected. So how do I fix this ?

Here is how it looks like

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `testing`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_SELECT_DATA_DETAIL`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`testing1`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_SELECT_DATA_DETAIL`(
    IN _Project_No VARCHAR(100),
    IN _status VARCHAR(20)
        
    )
BEGIN
SET @Project_No = _Project_No;
SET @status = _status;

SET @sqlStatement = CONCAT('SELECT A.Project_Description, B.Short_Name, UPPER(IF(A.Project_Status = '' '', "OPEN", A.Project_Status)) AS Project_Status
FROM project_detail A
LEFT JOIN company B ON A.`Customer` = B.`Com_ID`
WHERE 1 = 1 AND 
CASE 
WHEN RTRIM(''',@Project_No,''') = '' THEN RTRIM(''',@Project_No,''') ELSE A.`Project_No` END 
LIKE CONCAT(''%'', RTRIM(''',@Project_No,'''), ''%'')');


IF @status <> "All" THEN
 SET @SqlWhereStatement = CONCAT(' AND A.Project_Status = ''', @Status, '''');
 SET @SqlStatement = CONCAT(@SqlStatement, @SqlWhereStatement);
END IF;

SET @SqlOrderBy =CONCAT(' ORDER BY Project_No DESC ');
SET @SqlStatement=CONCAT(@SqlStatement,@SqlOrderBy);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then I tried to call it like this
`CALL SP_BOM_DETAILED_SELECT_PROJECT_DETAILS('8023', 'All')`

It supposed to show the row selected however, the only came out was [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0xW2.png) instead. I don't know where I did wrong. So, I'm hoping some help for anyone who knows. Thanks in advance.